# Where is my tablet mounting?

Tags: usb, file-management

I inherited a slight old Lenovo Tablet, an A2107A-F and I am trying to figure out what directory I'm looking at when I mount it as USB storage.  I don't have an `sdcard` currently.

The folder list I see includes:

```
100ANDRO
Alarms
Android
com.zinio.mobile.android.reader
DCIM
documents
Download
factory
kindle
LazyList
lenovo
LOST.DIR
Movies
Music
My Pictures
My SugarSync Folders
My Videos
Notifications
ooVooCache
```

But when I try to find "Movies" or "My Videos" in the file manager I don't see them. I see these files and directories:

```
acct
advanced_meta_init.project.rc
advanced_meta_init.rc
cache
config
d
data
default.prop
dev
emmc@android
emmc@cache
emmc@ebr1
emmc@fac
emmc@fat
emmc@sec_ro
emmc@usrdata
etc
fac
init
init.aee.customer.rc
init.factory.rc
init.goldfish.rc
init.project.rc
init.rc
init.setcc.rc
init.usb.rc
meta_init.rc
mnt
proc
res
root
sbin
sdcard
sys
system
ueventd.goldfish.rc
ueventd.rc
vendor
```

I expected the mounted folders to appear in "data" but the ES File Manager says that `/data/` is empty.

Not that the ES File Manager launches with a warning that I'm missing my SDcard (true. I am.)

Comment: You need to browse into sdcard directory there. That's where the user accessible file system exists. Your file manager by default should not be opening the root directory. Since it is ES file manager you can choose to bookmark the location of /sdcard for easy access. Long press the sdcard directory to get such an option.

Comment: I don't have an SD Card. So when I browse to `/sdcard/` it just tells me `SD Card empty, unmounted, or not present`

Comment: You mentioned USB Storage. Are you using Jelly Bean or an earlier Android version? Furthermore, are you trying to access `/sdcard` from that file manager when the USB Storage is mounted already? It wouldn't work in that case.